# ng-2-smart-table checkbox checked or not depending on value of column

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I have an ng2-smart-table whose second column I want to be a checkbox which is by default checked or empty depending on the fourth column binary value of the data object that is my source. So now I have

```
export class UsermanagementComponent implements OnInit {
  settings:Object;
  data:Object;
  public input: string = '<input type="checkbox"></input>';

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  this.settings = {
    columns: {
    username: {
      title: 'User Name'
    },
    checkbox: {
      title: 'Inactive',
      type: 'html',
      valuePrepareFunction: (value) => { return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.input); },
      filter: false
    }
  }
};

this.data = [
  {
    username: "Bret",
    checkbox:'yes'
  },
  {
    username: "Antonette",
    checkbox:'no'
  }
]; 
}
```

I have imported Ng2SmartTableModule and DomSanitizer as required. This is populating the checkbox with no relation whatsoever to what is set in checkbox in this.data. Same with checkbox:true or checkbox:1. Which I expected. Because nowhere have I mapped that if checkbox:yes then set that public string for the ith object iterable to be

```
<input type = 'checkbox' checked></input>
```

How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you just looking for something like `<input [(ngModel)]="checkboxValue" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">`?

Comment: Maybe but how do I map that to the ng-2-smart-table's source data object?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
...
public settings = {
  columns: {
    checkbox: {
      title: 'Check Box',
      type: 'html',
      valuePrepareFunction: (value) => { return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.input); },
      filter: false
    },
  }
};
...
public input: string = '<input type="checkbox">/input>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    export class UsermanagementComponent implements OnInit {
  settings:Object;
  data:Object;
  public checkedinput: string = '<input type="checkbox" checked></input>';
  public uncheckedinput: string = '<input type="checkbox"></input>';

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  this.settings = {
    columns: {
    username: {
      title: 'User Name'
    },
    checkbox: {
      title: 'Inactive',
      type: 'html',
      valuePrepareFunction: (value) => { 
          return value==true
            ? this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.checkedinput)
            : this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.uncheckedinput); },
      filter: false
    }
  }
};

this.data = [
  {
    username: "Bret",
    checkbox:'yes'
  },
  {
    username: "Antonette",
    checkbox:'no'
  }
]; 
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).